# Is it allowed to directly copy paste a meta post from one of the network sites to another?

Tags: discussion, meta, plagiarism

Every now and then when I'm crawling through meta sites, I come across a post brilliantly written, addressing a common issue. Cross posting as such is not permittable on the main sites, but can I copy paste an entire post?

This is blatant plagiarism, but it would make life easier. Example: *[Are people voting less than they used to on Physics SE?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10728/are-people-voting-less-than-they-used-to-on-physics-se)*.

Answer (score 4):

You could certainly introduce the other post, attribute it to its author, and link to the source. After which, put it in block quotes to make it obvious that it's not part of your own text. (You will want to provide something more substantial than *just* the other text, however. For instance, a bit of commentary of your own.) It's also likely that not all of the other post would be appropriate for a new post.

What you *shouldn't* do is nothing more than a copy and paste without anything else. "Blatant plagiarism" may be "easier," but that doesn't mean you should engage in it.

In fact, even if it's your *own* text, you still need to provide the appropriate attribution and source link. Otherwise, you fall foul of what's called self-plagiarism.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not. Especially in this specific case, having more up-to-date, site-specific stats would help.

It's probably always better to write in your own voice and refer liberally to the other post as needed.

So, no, there's rarely a good reason to, and you certainly should keep in mind fair attribution.